# How to sum-up number variables in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, numbers

I'm new to XSL,
and i'm wrote next code for counting sum of Win values.

```
<xsl:variable name="WinAmount">
        <xsl:number value="number(0)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Event">
            <xsl:if test="SpinTheReelsInfo">
                <xsl:number value="number(number($WinAmount) + number(SpinTheReelsInfo/Win))"/>
            </xsl:if>   
            <xsl:if test="SpinFreeReelsInfo">
                <xsl:number value="number(number($WinAmount) + number(SpinFreeReelsInfo/Win))"/>
            </xsl:if>               
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$WinAmount"/>
```

in my xml file win tags are matched to the next values.

```
<Win>0</Win>
....
<Win>20</Win>
.....
<Win>200</Win>
```

But the result is 121201
I'm think it's because numbers concatenated and because every number
incremented.

But why is this happening? And how can i sum them? Which operator can i use for this?
PLease, help me!
Thank you!

**Update: my XML**

```
<Game>
            <GameSeqNo>1</GameSeqNo>
            <Event>
                <Time>2012-12-20T08:24:26Z</Time>
                <SpinTheReelsInfo>
                    <Win>0</Win>
                    <JP>0</JP>
                </SpinTheReelsInfo>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Time>2012-12-20T08:24:42Z</Time>
                <PickFieldInfo>
                </PickFieldInfo>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Time>2012-12-20T08:25:07Z</Time>
                <SpinFreeReelsInfo>
                    <Win>20</Win>
                    <JP>0</JP>
                </SpinFreeReelsInfo>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Time>2012-12-20T08:25:18Z</Time>
                <SpinFreeReelsInfo>
                    <Win>200</Win>
                    <JP>0</JP>
                </SpinFreeReelsInfo>
            </Event>
</Game>
```

Comment: Pavel, consider to show us a small input sample and the corresponding output you want to create with XSLT, then we can suggest a proper XSLT solution. It might be that `sum(Event/SpinTheReelsInfo/Win | Event/SpinFreeReelsInfo/Win)` is all you need but it is usually easier to help when we see XML input and wanted output than trying to guess from not working code samples what the poster intends to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my suggestion in the comment suffices, here is a complete stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="Game">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(Event/SpinTheReelsInfo/Win | Event/SpinFreeReelsInfo/Win)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is `220`.